SQL: Entity that belongs to either one or another entity
I have a question about a scenario similar to the one described here:
SQL: Entity belongs (many-to-one) one of two different entities
Let's say that I get the need of the Party table and all the other referecend to it. But I'm curious to know in the PartyType table, what is the need of the Name column? I mean, it's just to keep "Person" or "Organization" varchar?
In the same way, in the Party table, what is the Name column for?
And also, what is the need of the PartyType table at all? I mean, is it just to have a place to insert all types and more importantly assure that when inserting, if there is wrong PartyTypeCd (not present in the PartyType table) we get an error, right?
Another question is, how would you go about inserting an Organization or a Person? Seeing the proposed schema, Organization and Person tables have their own ids (PersonId and OrganizationId respectively) which reference both the PartyId in the Party table. So, does this mean that we should insert a new Person (for example), in the Party table first? If this is the case, shouldn't there be an AUTO INCREMENT on the PartyId column in the Party table, so that we're sure that we don't get Organization and Person with same id?
As it is, the PartyId cannot be the only primary key. The primary key in Party table should be a combined one between PartyTypeCd and PartyId.
My situation is similar, in a way to that of the linked question on the top. Just for reference, here is a small schema example.

Basically I have a situation where a Component (that has it's own columns like component, and price) can either be associated to a User_Brand or to a System_Brand (both have their own unique columns and fields, which I have excluded from the screenshot..so merging them into one table with a type column is NOT a solution).

Why is it that PartyId cannot be the only primary key?

@GiannisTsimarakis because I was thinking that you insert in Person or Organization first..obviously, as you explained, I was wrong. If the case was that inserting has to be done on Person or Organization first, you could end up with the same OrganizationId or PersonId in the Party table..that was why I thought there is a need of a combine primary key..

As you correctly determined, using the standard method of subtypes is the way to go.

But I'm curious to know in the PartyType table, what is the need of the Name column? I mean, it's just to keep "Person" or "Organization" varchar?

Well, yes, and every other type you may add in the future. If you don't think you need it don't use it, but why not include some more descriptive information about what each PartyTypeCd is about close by.

In the same way, in the Party table, what is the Name column for?

This is a quite different case, and the linked answer is incomplete in that regard. I think the intent was to have Name as the actual "natural" key that the surrogate PartyId replaces as a PK. Still it is an Alternate Key and should have a unique constraint. You need it for the same reason you need a key everywhere else, a surrogate is useless on its own.

And also, what is the need of the PartyType table at all? I mean, is it just to have a place to insert all types and more importantly assure that when inserting, if there is wrong PartyTypeCd (not present in the PartyType table) we get an error, right?

Yes.

Another question is, how would you go about inserting an Organization or a Person? Seeing the proposed schema, Organization and Person tables have their own ids (PersonId and OrganizationId respectively) which reference both the PartyId in the Party table. So, does this mean that we should insert a new Person (for example), in the Party table first?

Yes, you need to insert the basetype Party and then the subtype Person/Organization.

If this is the case, shouldn't there be an AUTO INCREMENT on the PartyId column in the Party table, so that we're sure that we don't get Organization and Person with same id?

PartyId is unique. PartyId is PersonId or OrganizationId, but still unique regardless of which one. There is no way you get an Organization and Person with the same id.
There is a lot more info in the answers linked inside the one you linked to.

sir, you saved my day! Thank you for clarifying all my doubts about the linked question! Now my understanding of this subtypes approach is much clearer! Thank you very much!

Glad I could help!
